# Two python2 in the cmd and cannot use pip2 for any of the version

Tags: python, macos, cmd, pip

I am using `OS X 10.12` and I have some troubles with my python installation. Currently I have two python2 installed. One is `Python 2.7.10` at `/Library/Python/2.7` and the other is `Python 2.7.13` at `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1`. At the moment, all the pips (pip2, pip2.7, pip) direct to `Python 2.7.10`, and I cannot use `pip` for `Python 2.7.13` in the cmd. Even `Python 2.7.10` has pips, they do not work, for example, when I tried to upgrade `numpy`, I got error messages like this:

`Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.13.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (4.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.6MB 162kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-N61eSI-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'`

What I want to do is to make `pip` in the cmd for `Python 2.7.13` and make `pip2` for `Python 2.7.10`. And I want them both work.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method to do this would be to just use -m pip.

```
<path to python 2.7.10> -m pip
<path to python 2.7.13> -m pip
```

Or you could add the python 2.7.10 and 2.7.13 to environment variables and just use

```
<python 2.7.10> -m pip
<python 2.7.13> -m pip
```

While there are methods to just rename their respective pip to a different name, since I've never really used OSX, I'll leave that for more experienced people to answer.